# How to make route URL for configuration button in nopCommerce plugin list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 3.40. And I am developing a plugin.

For that I've added route for configure method.

```
  routes.MapRoute("Nop.Plugin.abc.xyz.Configure", "Admin/Plugins/abc/xyz/Configure",
                       new { controller = "Controller", action = "Configure" },
                       new[] { "Nop.Plugin.abc.xyz.Configure.Controllers" }
                       ).DataTokens.Add("area", "admin");
```

Then my URL looks like: `http://domainname/Admin/Plugins/abc/xyz/Configure` from plugin menu.

But when I click on configure button on plugin listing page, URL looks like:

```
http://domainname/Admin/Plugin/ConfigureMiscPlugin?systemName=abc.xyz
```

But I want display like :  `http://domainname/Admin/Plugins/abc/xyz/Configure`

My code for configure button:

```
 public void GetConfigurationRoute(out string actionName, out string controllerName, out RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
        {
            actionName = "Configure";
            controllerName = "SMSProvider";
            routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary() { { "Namespaces", "Nop.Plugin.abc.xyz.Controllers" }, { "area", null } };

        }
```

So, what should I do in `GetConfigurationRoute` method for custom Route.

Comment: Are you still having the problem in 3.8 ?